# Accidentally set Gmail to bypass inbox and send all emails to trash

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I was setting filters to automatically move junk emails to trash.  Unfortunately, I managed to set filter moving all emails- incoming and sent — to trash. I can’t find a way to get rid of filter. I managed, using “settings”, then “filters…”  to remove filters from certain email senders , but only about 25 senders— junk and not junk, are in that list. So can’t pickup everything that way. Plus, I can’t remove filter from new senders. I want my inbox and sent file back! Help!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the rules will not undo anything they have done.  You will need to go into the trash and select all your messages and then move them back out.